# Xcode 5 UIScrollView: drag and drop to code

Tags: xcode5

I am trying build a simple page controller in Xcode. Connecting my Xcode UIScrollView to code (through the control + drag method) is not working. I am trying to connect it to the scroll view property in a PageViewController.h file.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the property in the .h file, simply head over to your storyboard and select the ViewController that contains the ScrollView. Then select the connections inspector for the view controller and it should show the name of your scrollview. Simply click inside the connection bubble and drag to your ViewController and you'll see a popup stating UIScrollView. Once you see that, just release the mouse and you should be connected.